# How do I configure TFS to work with GMail to send TFS Alerts?

Tags: iis-7, tfs, web-config

Environment: Windows Server 2008, IIS 7.0, TFS 2008

We run Google Apps for email and I'm having a heck of time setting up TFS to send alerts to our Google hosted mail.

I googled around and found a couple of workarounds however none have worked for me. Any pointers graciously accepted.

Comment: From looking online, it sounds like the "TFS Web Access" has the ability to use authentication, but regular TFS does not. Your best bet it probably to set up a local SMTP server on the TFS server that will forward mail, authenticated, to the Gmail servers. Please post back once you decide and get it implemented.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried setting up an SMTP server on the same box as TFS, then configuring it to forward to GMail?  That sounds like the easiest solution.

Alternatively, you could write a [SOAP endpoint that handled TFS events](http://blogs.vertigosoftware.com/teamsystem/archive/2006/07/03/Subscribing_to_Team_Foundation_Server_Events.aspx) with as many customizations as you want.  This is a little more work but a lot more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran through this problem in TFS-2013.

I think the root of the problem is that Apps must sign into Google Securely. For secondary apps, that means oauth. For those that can't, Google needs "[Application Specific Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)". Since it can't really trust the email application, it requires you to generate a random password for that specific account.

The solution for me was:

```
Enable Email Alerts
    SMTP Server: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    SSL Required: Yes
    send from: email@mydomain.com

authentication:
    username: mygmail@gmail.com
    password: RANDOM APP PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just configure TFS to send outgoing email through the Gmail servers?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400808(VS.80).aspx

Does that not do what you need, or am I missing part of the question? We're using a local SMTP server to send email out, but I don't see a reason why you couldn't use a remote one instead.

Comment: This would be ideal -- I assumed he had already tried that but TFS had trouble authenticating, or something like that.

Comment: Ah - I hadn't considered that. The article I sent doesn't talk about SMTP authentication, and it would make sense that this is the portion he's having trouble with.

Comment: That is the problem (authentication)

Answer (score 0):

I verified that WernerCD AppPassword solution works.

Comment: Best to delete this, simply Upvote WernerCDs answer instead of posting another answer that it works.